# How to traverse DOM (children/siblings) using watir-webdriver?

Tags: php, ruby, dom, html-parsing, watir-webdriver

I'm used to using PHP's [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)(SHDP) to access elements, but I'm using ruby now with watir-webdriver, and I'm wondering if this can replace the functionality of SHDP as far as accessing elements on pages goes.

So in SHDP I'd do this:

```
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Which is an array of all instances of `div`s with `id=foo`. Oh, and `$html` is the HTML source of a specified URL. Anyway, so then I'd put it in a loop:

```
foreach($ret as $element) 
       echo $element->first_child ()->first_child ()->first_child ()->first_child ()->first_child ()->first_child ()->first_child ()->plaintext . '<br>';
```

Now, here, each `->first_child()` is a child of the parent `div` with `id=foo` (notice I have seven) and then I print the plaintext of the 7th child. Something like this

```
<div id="foo">
    <div ...>
        <div ...>
            <div ...>
                <div ...>
                    <div ...>
                        <div ...>
                            <div ...>HAPPINESS</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

would get "HAPPINESS" printed. So, my question is, how can this be done using watir-webdriver (if it all possible)?

Also, and more generally, how can I get SHDP's DOM-traversing abilities in watir-webdriver:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EnQp.png)

I ask because if watir-webdriver can't do this, I'm going to have to figure out a way to pipe source of a browser instance in watir-webdriver to a PHP script that uses SHDP and get it that way, and somehow get it back to ruby with the relevant information...

Comment: Documentation/reference would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watir implements an :index feature (zero-based):

```
browser.div(id: 'foo').divs           # children
browser.div(id: 'foo').div(index: 6)  # nth-child
browser.div(id: 'foo').parent         # parent
browser.div(id: 'foo').div            # first-child
browser.div(id: 'foo').div(index: -1) # last-child
```

`next_sibling` and `previous_sibling` are not currently implemented, please make a comment here if you think it is necessary for your code: https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/270

Note that in general you should prefer using indexes to using collections, but these also work:

```
browser.div(id: 'foo').divs.first
browser.div(id: 'foo').divs.last
```

Paperback code example (are you looking to select by text or obtain the text?):

```
browser.li(text: /Paperback/)  
browser.td(class: "bucket").li
browser.table(id: 'productDetailsTable').li
```

We've also had requests in the past to support things like direct children instead of parsing all of the descendants: https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/329

We're actively working on how we want to improve things in the upcoming versions of Watir, so if this solution does not work for you, please post a suggestion with your ideal syntax for accomplishing what you want here: https://github.com/watir/watir/issues and we'll see how we can support it.

Comment: See titusfortner's comment on David Shute's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a .child method to do this for you. If you know it will always be seven child divs in that structure you could do the inelegant

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
puts @browser.div(id: 'foo').div.div.div.div.div.div.div.text
```

You can always grab a collection of them and then address the last one, assuming it is the last one, the deepest in the stack.

```
puts @browser.div(id: 'foo').divs.last.text
```

That would also work, but assumes something absolute about the structure of the page. It's also not equivalent to the iteration of elements you've got above. As I'm not clear on the value of doing it that way I'm not comfortable taking a stab at equivalent code.

Comment: What about something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b759255a19e5fbf298e36fe66320d092) to access the text "Paperback:"?

Comment: Would you do `@browser.table(id: 'productDetailsTable').tr.td.???` where `???` is me not knowing how to handle siblings.

Comment: @Forwarding - if you want direct sibling support, please chime in here: https://github.com/watir/watir/pull/270

Comment: @titusfortner, well, then, how would you do this in XPath?

Comment: @Forwarding https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/locate-a-sibling-from-a-watir-element/comment-page-1/

Comment: @titusfortner, that is prettier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am not giving you exactly what you were doing in PHP. However, if you know that text of 7th child will be `HAPPINESS` then you could simply locate an element via XPath:

**STEPS:**

```
Given(/^I click the div "(.*?)" xpath$/) do |div_xpath|
  Watir::Wait.until { @browser.div(:xpath => div_xpath).exist? }
                      @browser.div(:xpath => div_xpath).click
end
```

**FEATURE:**

```
Given I click the div "//div[@id='foo'][text()='HAPPINESS']" xpath
```

Comment: Please try to avoid using the XPath selector with Watir. The Watir API makes it almost completely unnecessary, and it is horrible to read. :) If you want to match an element based on text, please use: `@browser.div(text: "HAPPINESS")`